# How does CCActionSequence process actions?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am learning Cocos2D v3 by examples, and I have test codes like:

```
- (void) move: (CGPoint) direction {
    ...
    while (TURE) {
        [self takeAction]; // self is an instance of CCNode subclass
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0];
    }
    ...
}

- (void) moveComplete {
    CCLOG(@"end action: %.3f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
}

- (void) takeAction {
    ...
    CCLOG(@"begin action: %.3f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actions: [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration: 0.2f position: newPosition], [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(moveComplete)], nil];
    [tile runAction: sequence];
}
```

Basically the flow would be "takeAction" is called (in a loop for test purpose) and then I let the main thread sleep for 1 second. I use "CCActionSequence" in "takeAction" to run a action and calls the "moveComplete" callback.

My question is simple: I can see the "begin action" log second by second (in sequence), but why I see the "end action" logs printed almost in the same time? Does CCActionSequence process actions in batch or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: no no no, the while(true) construct is completely wrong (besides that you wrote TURE). You can't just put the thread to sleep, that'll block everything. If you got this from some example code I suggest you work with different examples. Instead add a cccallblock or func to the end of the sequence that runs whateved code you need at the end of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Steffen. The thread sleep is bad, however I still can not catch you. Just assume we can do the sleep, so we see the "begin action" printed second by second, but why "end action" logs printed not second by second?? Thanks.

Comment: Because thread sleep prevents the actions from advancing. You're blocking the main thread, *nothing* is running. It's the same as having a loop where you call takeAction an infinite number of times.

Comment: Yeah what you are doing is a definite no no, you should use `[CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:1.0f]` in order for a pause to happen, and instead of the loop consider using `CCActionRepeatForever`